# Vertical border matching visual text block height instead of box height

Tags: html, css, typography

Is there any way to get the border height always the height of the visual text block (from cap height of the first line to descender of the last line) instead of the physical height of the parent element?

As you can see here, the left border line is always sticking out above the text and also below. So we need to crop that few excessive pixels of the border to match the text's visual block height. I tried below or should there be another way to do this. It should not be a fixed height due to text that displays wider and narrower on different screen sizes.

I tried to crop the border line with padding, margin, height at 95% but all don't work.

```css
.line-left-blue {
  border-left: 8px solid #007dc3;
  padding-left: 14px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-left-blue">
  <h2>Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus.</h2>
  <div>Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.</div>
</div>
```

[image: Heading and two lines of smaller text with red horizontal lines denoting highest (cap height or ascender) and lowest (descender) points to where glyphs reach. On the left there is thick blue border with area above and below red lines hatched in red.]

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding your question correctly - you want CSS to trim the line height from the top of the `cap height` (top of a capital letter) to the bottom of the `descender` (e.g. the tail on a lower case 'p') ?

If my understanding is correct then the answer is 'no'.

There is a proposal with the CSS Working Group on a similar matter, where you would be able to control line height in the same way as `leading` works in the print world, which can be seen here:

[CSS-inline leading control](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3240)

There is a related 'solution' to the this problem, in terms of getting CSS line height to work like leading, in this CSS Tricks article:

[How to Tame Line Height in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-tame-line-height-in-css/)

**Some simple work arounds**

*Using the pipe `|` character*

This character (generally) honours the cap height.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="pipe">|</span> T</p>
```

*Using An Empty Span Element*

If you have access to the HTML you can add a `<span>` element inside the opening tag of the text, and then style this accordingly.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.border-effect {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2.1rem;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1rem;
  bottom: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="border-effect"></span>T</p>
```

*Using a Pseudo Element*

If you don't have access to the HTML you can use either the `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3rem;
  display: inline-flex;
}

p::before {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 2.1rem;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1rem;
  bottom: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<p>T</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mean a vertical line next to a text. The height of this (created with border-left in this case) always fills up to the height of the div it's in and therefore always sticks out a few pixels above and below the text. So i'm looking for a way to trim the line to the cap height of the text and below to the descender.

Comment: @T-Design I've added some more simple work arounds to the answer if you are simply looking for a left border effect.

Comment: yes this works, although if it needs to display next to the whole paragraph of text I changed the .border-effect height to a percentage instead of a fixed height, which also had the desired effect.

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help. If you think it's good enough for a correct answer feel free to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround to trim the vertical line next to a paragraph of text. Basically created with a single colored image as background image. Then set the height with a percentage to have a precise control of the height. square.jpg could be a single colored 10x10 px image for example.

```css
.vertical-line {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red,red);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 4px 90%;
  background-position: left center;
}

.margin {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-line">
  <h3 class="margin"><strong>Header title</strong><br> Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.</h3>
</div>
```